# Arraylist of arraylist...in c#

Tags: c#, arraylist

I need to get data from a SQL query, I have a method that returns me an arraylist of arraylist, but I am not able to show me the data returned by the query sql.

I write the method returns the sql query:

```
public ArrayList ejecutarSelect(string sentenciaSQL){

    if (this.conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)this.Conectar();

    ArrayList rows = new ArrayList();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sentenciaSQL, this.conn);
    try
    {
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                ArrayList row = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++) row.Add(dataReader.GetString(i));
                rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        dataReader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        CLog.log("ERROR (CDBMgr): " + e.Message);
        return null;
    }

    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use non-generic collections in the first place?

Comment: "I am not able to show me the data returned by the query sql" -> So what do you get instead?

Comment: I need to retrieve all the items in that table, but not how to access an arraylist into another arraylist.


sorry for my English ...

Comment: can you use Entity Framework to make things easier for yourself?

Comment: OP gets *null* or an empty `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
row.Add(dataReader[i].ToString());
```

See [SqlDataReader.GetString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/007ek5d0.aspx).

It says

> No conversions are performed; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string.

So ..